# Oracle Linux (RHEL) 6.6 very bad performance - what's going on?

Tags: linux, oracle, performance, permissions, disk

I have a problem with Oracle Linux 6.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux).
The performance is very poor, due to heavy disk usage. The CPU usage is normal on idle systems, but disk works so hard, that even writing file edited in VIM takes a lot of time.
 The only strange thing I observed is "Permission denied" to some processed (e.g. yum background process) trying to access files in /proc.
 Could this be a reason for that bad performance? What could I do do make this work?

Regards!

Comment: Performance of what? Probably off topic here. http://superuser.com/ might be a better place to ask, but you really need to give *a lot more details* (what processes are running, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a process is performing many reads/writes or the system is swapping.

***top***

"O", "p" "Enter"

- to sort the output of top by swap usage

***free -m***

- to check if the system runs out of memory and uses swap

You should check your log folders, e.g. an application or middleware has set a detailed loglevel and is writing many lines to logfiles.